# Spark Exception “Cannot broadcast the table that is larger than 8GB” , 'spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold': '-1' not working

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, broadcast, pyspark

In one of our Pyspark jobs we have a scenario where  we are doing a  join between a large data frame and  relatively smaller data frame , I believe that spark is using broadcast join and we ran in to the following error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot broadcast the table that is larger than 8GB: 8 GB
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:75)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

I tried disabling broadcast join by setting  'spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold': '-1'  as a part of spark submit

```
/usr/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1 /home/hadoop/scripts/job.py
```

I tried print the value of spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold  using

```
spark.conf.get("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold")
```

and it returns -1 . However even after this change i am getting the error

```
   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cannot broadcast the table that is larger than 8GB: 8 GB
```

The spark version is  Spark 2.3.0

Any help  is appreciated.

Comment: how the code looks like? Are you using maybe `broadcast` function explicitly?

Comment: The following is the query I am running

select table1.id, table2.xxx,table2.yyyy from table1  inner join table2 on table2.id =  table1.id

I did an explain and looks like it is using  BroadcastNestedLoopJoin

The table1 has about 2343649686 and table2  511284

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using maybe broadcast function explicitly. Even if you set spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1 and use a broadcast function explicitly, it will do a broadcast join.

Another reason might be you are doing a Cartesian join/non equi join which is ending up in Broadcasted Nested loop join (BNLJ join). As mentioned you better use the explain and understand what is happening.

To convert an optimized logical plan into physical plan, Spark uses some set of strategy. For Joins, Spark uses JoinSelection.

The way it works is documented here - https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/aefb2e7/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/SparkStrategies.scala#L326

Join Physical Operator Selection Requirements For BroadcastNestedLoopJoinExec -

There are no join keys and one of the following holds:

1) Join type is CROSS, INNER, LEFT ANTI, LEFT OUTER, LEFT SEMI or ExistenceJoin (i.e. canBuildRight for the input joinType is positive) and right join side can be broadcast

2) Join type is CROSS, INNER or RIGHT OUTER (i.e. canBuildLeft for the input joinType is positive) and left join side can be broadcast

OR

No other join operator has matched already

Comment: The following is the query I am running

select table1.id, table2.xxx,table2.yyyy from table1  inner join table2 on table2.id =  table1.id

I did an explain and looks like it is using  BroadcastNestedLoopJoin

The table1 has about 2343649686 and table2  511284

Comment: One of the places where nested loop join is used independently of the dataset size is cross join resulting on cartesian product. In this situation each row from the left table is returned together with every row from the right table, if there is no predicate defined. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The smaller data frame that was used in the join was reused in multiple places. So  cache the data frame before the join and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you explain the join and see the physical plan? By default, it will join using broadcast and if you disable it, it will use the sort join

```
print(spark.conf.get("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold"))
# should give 10Mb as default
```

and if you disable it

```
spark.conf.get("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold")
print(spark.conf.get("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold"))
#-1
```

you better use the explain and understand what is happening.

Comment: The following is the query I am running

select table1.id, table2.xxx,table2.yyyy from table1  inner join table2 on table2.id =  table1.id

I did an explain and looks like it is using  BroadcastNestedLoopJoin

The table1 has about 2343649686 and table2  511284